# Flutter Chopper library cache http response

Tags: flutter, chopper

in my mobile application i'm using [Chopper](https://pub.dev/packages/chopper) `http` library and i would like to cache http response with this library, my server return this headers with responses:

```
<-- 200 http://www.www.www/api/v1/dashboard/allData
content-type: application/json
cache-control: max-age=600, private
transfer-encoding: chunked
date: Mon, 07 Sep 2020 05:47:00 GMT
server: Apache
```

i added this interceptor to `chopper` interceptors:

```
final client = ChopperClient(

client: http.IOClient(
  HttpClient()..connectionTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 60),
),
baseUrl: webUri,
services: [
  _$WebApi(),
],
converter: const JsonConverter(),
interceptors: [
  const HeadersInterceptor({'Content-Type': 'application/json','Cache-Control':'private, max-age=600'}),
  HttpLoggingInterceptor(),
]);
```

now i expect cache work fine for my application, this solution is correct?

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: @nvoigt my app try to get data from server always, i expect after disable internet connection, data should be get from cache, but it doesn't work

Comment: What are you using for cache? It looks like Chopper doesn't have a caching mechanism, I couldn't find anything about that on docs.

Comment: @Can i don't have any experience about caching mechanism and i don't implemented  cache mechanism

Comment: In this case there is no cache and your app needs an internet connection to make the request.

Comment: @Can so how can i implement this mechanism? is it difficult?

Comment: You can have a look at the dio package.
https://pub.dev/packages/dio
I haven't used it myself but I have found an example using a cache interceptor.
https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/example/custom_cache_interceptor.dart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221078/discussion-between-doldurma-and-can).